# Run a instance method in a button action method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question. I think I don't unterstand something.

I got a class, with variables, and a methods.

- AppDelegate.h/.m
- WifMon.h./m <-- the one mentioned above
- ViewController.h./m

So now I create an instance of WifMon in my ViewController.m (header of WifMon is included.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    WifMon *test = [[WifMon alloc] initWithData:"google.de" withPort:443];
}
```

No I got a button and want to start my "dynCheck" method.

```
- (IBAction)startCheck:(id)sender {
    //start dynCheck here
    [test dynCheck];       //this isn't working
}
```

But this isn't working.
I can't access my "test" instance inside the action method.

But why?

Comment: Surprise. No `Compile Time` Error Found ? as you created object in local scope with in `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: Actually, no surprise.

Comment: You guys should learn C at some basic level at least before trying to write ***The Best iPhone App Ever (TM)***...

Comment: You need to learn scope of Variable!

Comment: You're right. That was dumb :-)

But I don't want to write **the Best iPhone App ever**
It's ok, if it's just work.

Comment: Great, so now we have people not even *aiming* for ***Best iPhone App Ever***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `test` variable is valid only within `viewDidLoad` method.

To overcome this you need for example an instance variable. Better would be a property around `test`.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) WifMon* test;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.test = [[WifMon alloc] initWithData:"google.de" withPort:443];
}

- (IBAction)startCheck:(id)sender
{
    //start dynCheck here
    [self.test dynCheck];
}
```

Make attention if you don't use ARC!!! If not you should

```
self.test = [[[WifMon alloc] initWithData:"google.de" withPort:443] autorelease];
```

and

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    [_test release];
}
```

Comment: Tank you very much, that helped me out, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in C, it only exists in the **scope** in which it is declared. If you declare it inside a function, it only exists **inside that function**.

You need to declare `test` as an instance variable in your class if you want to be able to access it from all of the object's instance methods:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    WifMon *test;
}
```

Then `test` will be available in all instance methods of the object.

Alternatively, if you want the instance variable to be accessible by other objects, or be able to access it using `self.test`, you can declare it like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) WifMon *test;

...

@end
```

Then you can access it using `self.test`.

Note that this example is using ARC (which is enabled by default so you are probably already using it), but if you aren't, you will need to declare the property as `retain` instead of `strong`, and remember to release `test` in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Tank you very much, that helped me out.